# Inverse function for a formula

Tags: inverse-function

I used this code on Mathematica but it's not showing any result?!

```
InverseFunction[(A*ArcTanh[(#1*A)/Sqrt[#1^2*B - C]] -
  Sqrt[B]*ArcTanh[(#1*Sqrt[B])/Sqrt[#1^2*B - C]])/(A^2 - B) +
  (A*Log[#1^2*(A^2 - B) + C])/(2*(A^2 - B)) & ]
```

please consider that A, B, and C are positive.

Comment: Is that all the code you used? What do you expect it to show as a result? You really need to improve your question or it is likely it will get closed and deleted.

Comment: I want to know with the Table of A, B, and C, how should be inverse of this function!

Comment: The symbol `C` is a built-in symbol in the WL. Avoid the use of symbol names that start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2):

Symbolic inverse functions don't exist in general:

```
f = InverseFunction[Sin[#] + ArcSin[#] &]
(* InverseFunction[Sin[#1] + ArcSin[#1] &] *)
```

However, `Mathematica` can evaluate such things numerically:

```
f[1.5]
(* 0.736689 *)
```

Comment: How can I plot this inverse? for example plot inverse f'(x)/inverse f(x)

Comment: f[#1]:=A*ArcTanh[(#1*A)/Sqrt[#1^2*B - C]] -
  Sqrt[B]*ArcTanh[(#1*Sqrt[B])/Sqrt[#1^2*B - C]])/(A^2 - B) +
  (A*Log[#1^2*(A^2 - B) + C])/(2*(A^2 - B))